# How does php handle ajax post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Maybe I am just not as smart as I think I am but I really am having issues with aJax and PHP interacting with each other. I am trying to make a save method.

This is the PHP that I have. My only guess is that I am not checking the right things.

(this is a page called edit.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_GET['dir'])){
   $File = $_POST['location']; 
   $Handle = fopen($File, 'w') or die("can't open file");
   $Data = $_POST['text']; 
   fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
   fclose($Handle); 
}

?>
```

`<input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['dir'];?>" id="saveValue">`
This is the function that gets called when I push `Ctrl and S`

```
    function saveFile(){
var data = new FormData();
    data.append('text', e.getSession().getValue());
    data.append('location',$('#saveValue').val());
var url = $('#saveValue').val(); 
var split = url.split('/public_html'); 
    alert(split[1]);
var url = "edit.php?dir="+split[1];
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: data,

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data == "false") {
            console.log("There is a problem on the server, please try again later");    
        } else {
                //Do something with what is returned
                console.log("failed");
        }
    }
});      
};
```

I think that I am either checking the wrong thing or I am not submitting what I think I am.
May I please get some help or at least some clarification on this.

I have read that I need to use `$_REQUEST['text']` instead of `$_POST` but neither have worked.

Comment: Where is the `dir` parameter in your url?

Comment: Why you set `contentType` to `'multipart/form-data'`?

Comment: with `contentType: 'multipart/form-data', ` Are you trying to upload a file with ajax? I don't give it a chance to work

Comment: I updated the code (even on my server) and it still didn't submit the data I need. and the `dir` param is the directory the file is in. (I got it with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and then I split the doc root at (in my case) `/public_html` and that gets me the directory in terms of the server. and then I just get the file name.

Comment: You try to get `dir` from `$_GET` but you never submit it as a get parameter. To get it from `$_GET` your url should look like `edit.php?dir=foo`. Or maybe you mean `if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['location']))`?

Comment: I updated my code yet again and I am getting an illegal invocation on `$.ajax({`

Comment: Doing on fopen and write with completely unchecked post data is a Bad Idea TM.

Comment: It's not a bad idea because I am making a text editor for my server under a secure PDO login system and under a SHA512 hashed folder. It's more than secure.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you are trying to mix up two request types `GET` as well as `POST`.

In your `AJAX` call the URL you specify doesn't contain the `dir` parameter, as a consequence the condition `isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_GET['dir'])` fails.

You cannot have `edit.php?dir=foo` because you can have request method either `GET` or POST`

Your server side script has an `if()` condition to check for `POST` parameters. As suggested by @Marcel Gwerder it would be like `if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['location']))`

Happy to help.

Comment: I am now getting an illegal invocation. on `$.ajax({`

Comment: so, `GET` and `POST` can't work together. drop the $_GET['dir'] from the server side condition. I will edit my answer

Comment: The server side php shouldn't effect my `$.ajax` script. At least it shouldn't be causing the illegal invocation error

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope this resolves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed what was wrong with my code. Here is what I now have.

```
function getDir(){
var url = $('#saveValue').val(); 
    var split = url.split('/public_html'); 
    return split[1];
}; 


function saveFile(){
var datas = {
        'text': e.getValue(),
        'location':$('#saveValue').val()
        };
  $.ajax({
    url: "edit.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: datas,
      success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            errorReport(datas.toString());
      }
});      
};
function errorReport(data){
    var msg = document.createElement('p');
    msg.className = "msg";
    msg.innerHTML = data
    $('.error').append(msg);
    $('.msg').fadeIn('slow');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.msg').fadeOut("slow");
        $('.msg').remove();
    },9500);
};
```

and for the little bit of PHP that I had, I now have this.
From what I can tell I was not sending the right kind of object through the form.

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])  && isset($_POST['location'])){
   $File = $_POST['location'];  
   $Handle = fopen($File, 'w') or die("can't open file");
   $Data = $_POST['text']; 
   fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
   fclose($Handle); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using POST request with Ajax, some headers need to be set

```
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

This header makes php think of the data being submitted as a form submission. Now, the corresponding data can be handle in php as normal $_POST[] variables.